# Show contentview on frame tapgesture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a cross platform app using xaml forms and have yet to figured out how to call a ContentView ontapGesture. I am able to call ContentView on xaml forms using `<local:MailRoomList/>` but I cant show a view ontap or on click event.

I have tried to show view on stacklayout using `StackLayoutID.Children.Add(new MailRoomList());` but thats not what I want. I want to show full contentview on content page with back button enabled.

Please advise. Thank you

### MailRoomList

```XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="xx.xxxx.xx.Views.MailRoomList">
<ContentView.Content>
  <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="This is my MailRoom List" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

### OnTapGesture

```XAML
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnRegisterMail" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

### CodeBehind

```c#
async void OnRegisterMail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MailRoomList());
}
```

Edit:
Home Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xf1:BottomBarPage
         xmlns:xf1="clr-namespace:xx.xxxx.xx.BottomBar" 
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xx.xxxx.xx.Views"
        x:Class="xx.xxxx.xx.Views.Home">
<ContentPage x:Name="MailRoomPage" Title="MailRoom" Icon="mailroom.png" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="Orange" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.BadgeCount="5">
    <local:MailRoom/>
</ContentPage>

<ContentPage Title="Transport" Icon="transport.png" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="Green" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.BadgeCount="10">
    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Transport" FontSize="Large"/>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Communication" Icon="communication.png" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="Blue" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.BadgeCount="3">
    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Communication" FontSize="Large"/>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="HSE" Icon="hse.png" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="Red" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.BadgeCount="2">
    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="HSE" FontSize="Large"/>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Meeting" Icon="meeting.png" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="DarkCyan" xf1:BottomBarPageExtensions.BadgeCount="5">
    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Meeting" FontSize="Large"/>
</ContentPage>
```

From homepage above I am calling my view `<local:MailRoom/>` which is calling another view MailRoomList. This is where I need your advice on how to call a content view from another content view.

Comment: Is your app's MainPage a NavigationPage?

Comment: Yes, Home is my NavigationPage after login screen.
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Home());

Comment: Did you check if the OnRegisterMail function is actually being called after Tapping?
Also try 

Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MailRoomList());
});

Comment: If that doesn't work, please also post xaml and codebehind of your home page.

Comment: That doesnt work, throws error cannot convert from view to xamarin.forms.page. I am calling a from another view.

Answer (score 0):

`ContentView` is a `View` not a `Page`. Change your `MainRoomList` Xaml to this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="xx.xxxx.xx.Views.MailRoomList">
     <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is my MailRoom List" />
     </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage>
```

`View`'s dont support navigation, they can only be *navigated to* if they belong to a `Page` which are the objects that **contain** the navigation infrastructure.

IF you want to mantain your `MailRoomList` as a `ContentView`, then you need to include her in some **other page**, and perform the navigation ( inside the tap method ) to that **other** page